# how to grep line numbers of a text file after entries are displayed to the screen

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

ok so i am making a bash script to read a write from a file and i am having a problem with displaying entries to the screen with line numbers.

currently i can type in the name of the file and then type in a line number, after i type the line number it will print the line number that was chosen to the screen and ask if they want to delete it.

what i want to do is when the user selects the option to delete an entry it will ask them for the file name. the user will then type in a String and it will search the file for entries matching that description and print all entries that have matching content to the screen with line numbers next to them

currently this is the code i have developed:

```
echo "please enter the address book you would like to search in  "
read bookName
book="$bookName"

echo "Please Enter the name of the person you wish to look for  "
read search

echo "First Names , Surname , Occupation , Phone Number , Mobile Number , Address "
grep -i $search $bookName

grep -n $bookName
echo -n "What line number do you want to delete? "
read lineNumber
sed -n "$lineNumber p" $bookName
```

currently the search works for searching for people but it does not display the line numbers next to them and i know the delete function is not here but i have to code for it.

the main problems i am having is printing the entries found with line numbers next to them.

thanks

Comment: Is the reference to `bookName` a file?

Comment: yes it is a file that i have created already but there are more than one so i give the choice to choose the file

Comment: It's hard to make any sense of what you're trying to accomplish.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
grep -i $search "$bookName"
```

to

```
grep -in $search "$bookName"
```

And it will print line numbers for the matching lines.